# How do I elegantly use smart pointers to model complex lifetimes in C++?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, raii, object-lifetime

Suppose I have a collection of `Foo` objects, and each `Foo` owns one or more `Bar` objects. A specific `Foo` or `Bar` can be deleted by a user of my interface; when a `Foo` is deleted, all the `Bar`s it owns are deleted too. So far, giving each `Foo` a collection of `unique_ptr<Bar>` is all I need to automatically manage this model. However, I have an additional requirement: once a `Foo` is left without any `Bar`, it should also be deleted.

Of course, I could just write code that explicitly takes care of that, but I wonder if there's a more idiomatic way to achieve the same thing. That sounds an awful lot like a `shared_ptr`, but not quite...

Comment: Who owns the `Foo` collection? That's probably where the deletion of Foos should go.

Comment: You should enforce this condition by code, this is so specific that I doubt you would found an "elegant" idiomatic way of doing it. Just design a sound system

Comment: @Yaron Tausky: please have a look at my post, and mark it as the exact answer to your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since deleting all `Bar`s from a `Foo` should delete the `Foo`, it may indeed sound like you need a handful of `shared_ptr`s from `Bar`s to their `Foo`.

However, that model would place the lifetime of the `Foo` in the hands of its `Bar`s: you wouldn't be able to directly delete the `Foo`, instead you'd have to hunt down all of its `Bar`s and delete *these*.

`Foo` would keep `Bar*`s instead of `unique_ptr<Bar>`s, since it cannot die before its `Bar`s. But then you have to give ownership of the `Bar`s to *someone*...

You might end up with yet another object that holds the collection of `unique_ptr<Bar>`s corresponding to each of the `Foo`s, but then you have to keep all of this in sync as `Bar`s come and go. That's the same kind of bookkeeping you're trying to avoid, but a lot bigger, more complicated, and more brittle as a result, with memory leaks and rogue pointers as failure cases.

---

So instead of all of this, I suggest you stick with your first `unique_ptr`-powered idea. A first go at an implementation might look like this:

```
struct Foo {
private:
    friend void remove(std::unique_ptr<Foo> &foo, Bar const *bar);

    // Removes the bar from this Foo.
    // Returns true iff the Foo is now empty and should be deleted.
    bool remove(Bar const *bar) {
        auto i = std::find_if(begin(_bars), end(_bars), [&](auto const &p) {
            return p.get() == bar;
        });

        assert(i != end(_bars));
        _bars.erase(i);

        return _bars.empty();
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> _bars;
};

// Removes the bar from the Foo.
// Deletes the Foo if it becomes empty.
void remove(std::unique_ptr<Foo> &foo, Bar const *bar) {
    if(foo->remove(bar))
        foo.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no idiomatic solution. Use shared_ptr and unique_ptr inside of the aggregate and weak_ptr as anchor to the aggregate. Here is my elaborated example of your problem:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::unique_ptr;
using std::weak_ptr;
using std::make_shared;
using std::make_unique;

struct Foo;
struct Bar
{   int b;
    shared_ptr<Foo> f;
    Bar(int b, shared_ptr<Foo> f): b(b), f(f)  { cout << "Constructor B with: " <<b  << std::endl; }
    ~Bar() { cout << "Destructor B with: " <<b << endl; }
};
struct Foo
{
    Foo()  { cout << "Constructor Foo" << endl; }
    ~Foo() { cout << "Destructor Foo"  << endl; }
    void clear()  { vb.clear(); }
    vector<unique_ptr<Bar>> vb;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   weak_ptr<Foo> wf;  // Anchor to Aggregate
    {   // Construction of Aggregate
        vector<shared_ptr<Bar>> vb2;
        shared_ptr<Foo> f  =std::make_shared<Foo>();
        f->vb.emplace_back(make_unique<Bar>(1, f));
        f->vb.emplace_back(make_unique<Bar>(2, f));
        wf =f;
    }
    shared_ptr<Foo> f3 =wf.lock();
    if (f3)
    {
        if (argv[1][0] =='f')
        {
            cout <<"Destroy Foo" <<endl;
            f3->clear();
        }
        if (argv[1][0] =='b')
        {
            cout <<"Destroy Bar" <<endl;
            f3->vb[0].reset();
            f3->vb[1].reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Call the program with argument 'f' or 'b' and the output will be:

```
Constructor Foo
Constructor B with: 1
Constructor B with: 2
Destroy ???
Destructor B with: 1
Destructor B with: 2
Destructor Foo
```